# UserControl.ParentForm is Null

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, user-controls

I am working on a form that displays one of several user controls based on the selected index in a combo box.  The form is used for adding and editing different kinds of items (i.e. Service, Inventory, Non-Inventory, etc..) which contain different data fields.  The user controls need access to a few controls on the form before they can persist a Linq-to-SQL object.

The problem that I am have encountered is that the value of `UserControl.ParentForm` always returns null.  I realize that ideally the control should not be tightly coupled to the form but, I'd like to understand why this is happening before considering my re-factoring options.

Below, I have included the method in the form that adds the user controls and the method in the control that attempts to get the ParentForm.  Can someone give me suggestions on why the ParentForm might be NULL?

Form Code:

```
void comboBoxEditType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = comboBoxEditType.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (value == "DiscountItem")
    {
        if (itemControl != null)
            this.Controls.Remove(itemControl);

        labelControlDescriptionOfType.Text = "Use to subtract a percentage or fixed amount from a total or subtotal. "
                                           + "Do not use this item type for an early payment discount.";

        DiscountItemControl control = new DiscountItemControl();
        control.Location = new Point(13, 110);
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        itemControl = control;
    }
    else if (value == "InventoryItem")
    {
        if (itemControl != null)
            this.Controls.Remove(itemControl);

        labelControlDescriptionOfType.Text = "Use for goods you purchase, track as inventory, and resell.";

        InventoryItemControl control = new InventoryItemControl();
        control.Location = new Point(13, 110);
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        itemControl = control;
    }
    else if (value == "NonInventoryItem")
    {
        if (itemControl != null)
            this.Controls.Remove(itemControl);

        labelControlDescriptionOfType.Text = "Use for goods you buy but don't track, like office supplies, "
                                           + "or materials for a specific job that you charge back to the customer.";

        NonInventoryPartItemControl control = new NonInventoryPartItemControl();
        control.Location = new Point(13, 110);
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        itemControl = control;
    }
    else if (value == "OtherChargeItem")
    {
        if (itemControl != null)
            this.Controls.Remove(itemControl);

        labelControlDescriptionOfType.Text = "Use for miscellaneous labor, material, or part charges, such as delivery charges, "
                                           + "setup fees, and service charges.";

        OtherChargeItemControl control = new OtherChargeItemControl();
        control.Location = new Point(13, 110);
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        itemControl = control;
    }
    else if (value == "ServiceItem")
    {
        if (itemControl != null)
            this.Controls.Remove(itemControl);

        labelControlDescriptionOfType.Text = "Use for services you charge for or purchase, like specialized labor, consulting hours, or "
                                           + "professional fees.";

        ServiceItemControl control = new ServiceItemControl();
        control.Location = new Point(13, 110);
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        itemControl = control;
    }

    // Move the location of buttons
    int btnX = 12 + itemControl.Width + 10;
    btnSaveAndClose.Location = new Point(btnX, btnSaveAndClose.Location.Y);
    btnSaveAndNew.Location = new Point(btnX, btnSaveAndNew.Location.Y);
    btnCancel.Location = new Point(btnX, btnCancel.Location.Y);

    // Center the Make Inactive CheckBox on side of UserControl
    Point point = new Point();
    point.X = btnCancel.Location.X;
    point.Y = itemControl.Location.Y + itemControl.Size.Height / 2;
    checkEditMakeInactive.Location = point;

    // Resize the window to fit fit the control
    int windowWidth = 140 + itemControl.Width;
    int windowHeight = 150 + itemControl.Height;
    this.Size = new Size(windowWidth,windowHeight);

    // Resize the group containing information on the item type
    int groupWidth = itemControl.Width;
    int groupHeight = groupControlType.Height;
    groupControlType.Size = new Size(groupWidth, groupHeight);
    //this.groupControlType.Size

    // Resize the label
    int labelWidth = itemControl.Width - 27 - comboBoxEditType.Size.Width;
    labelControlDescriptionOfType.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelControlDescriptionOfType.Height);
}
```

User Control Code That Attempts to Get ParentForm (NULL Always Returned)

```
private void CopyItemDataFromForm()
{
    currentDiscountItem.Name = textEditItemName_Number.Text;
    if (checkEditSubItemOf.Checked)
    {
        currentDiscountItem.fkParentItem = ComboBoxHelper.getItemFromComboBox(comboBoxEditParentItem);
    }
    currentDiscountItem.SalesDescription = memoEditDescription.Text;
    currentDiscountItem.SalesPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(textEditAmountOrPercent.Text);
    currentDiscountItem.fkIncomeAccount = ComboBoxHelper.getQBLookUpFromComboBox(comboBoxEditAccount);
    currentDiscountItem.fkTaxCode = ComboBoxHelper.getQBLookUpFromComboBox(comboBoxEditTaxCode);


    AddEditItemForm form = this.ParentForm as AddEditItemForm;
    currentDiscountItem.IsActive = !(form.GetMakeInactiveCheckboxValue());
}
```

Comment: When I was searching for a solution, I did encounter that post.  But, in that particular case the user was attempting to get the ParentForm in the constructor.  My controls are not added through the designer and I am accessing them long after initialization has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Parent property, Gets the parent object of this FrameworkElement in the object tree.

```
var result = this.Parent;
```

Comment: The Parent property was also returning Null.  I stopped the code in the debugger to inspect and both Parent and ParentForm were Null.  I decided to just pass a reference to the ParentForm into the constructor to temporarily solve my problem until I refactor the code so that that controls do not depend on the form controls anymore.

Comment: i'am happy to help you but if you want another solution that's good

Comment: Candie, I'd definitely be interested in your suggestions as to why the ParentForm and Parent references are null in the control.